# 404 error when IE loads fonts

Tags: css, internet-explorer, http-status-code-404, font-face

I'm calling my fonts like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'dinar';
  src: url('../fonts/dinarm.eot?#'),
       local('?'),
       local('Mj_Dinar Two Medium'),
       url('../fonts/dinarm.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/dinarm.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/dinarm.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font-bmi';
  src: url('../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.eot') format('eot'),
       url('../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal
}
```

Every time some user with Internet Explorer tries to access the site, I see lots of 404 errors in web host usage log and finally the user get banned by my security plugin. There is an example of usage log:

```
80.00.000.146 - - [05/Apr/2017:00:46:10 +0430] 
"GET /wp-content/themes/fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.eot)%20format(%22eot%22),
%20url(../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.woff)%20format(%22woff%22),
%20url(../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.ttf)%20format(%22truetype%22 HTTP/1.1" 404 4058 
"http://www.21tech.ir/some-page/" "Mozilla/4.0 
(compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; --some other information--)"
```

I know it wrote `Mozilla/4.0` but it's IE actually I've tested it.

What's the problem and how can be solved or avoided?

Comment: The path should be relative to the css file itself, and not from the page that calls the css. Is it the right path ?

Comment: @iguypouf Yes, it just happens with IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that older versions of IE can't interpret the second `src` property in your second `@font-face` declaration properly. The solution, called the [Fontspring `@font-face` syntax](http://blog.fontspring.com/2011/02/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax/) is to append a single question mark (?) to the end of the .eot URL in that property, tricking IE into thinking everything that follows is a querystring:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"font-bmi";
    src:url("../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
        url("../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.woff") format("woff"),
        url("../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:normal
}
```

You've tried a few different "hacks" to solve the issue in your first `@font-face` declaration but, although you've successfully managed to prevent IE from reporting 404s, the above solution is much cleaner and doesn't affect the readability of your CSS.

For further reading, see Paul Irish's "[Bulletproof `@font-face` syntax](https://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/)" article from 2009.

Comment: Actually I see the error for my every font, the first one is not ok, I just paste part of the error. I tried what you advised but no success.

Comment: First link in your answer, did the job. Thanks.

Comment: What was the change you had to make and how did it differ from my solution?

Comment: Used this: `@font-face{font-family:'font-bmi';src:url('../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.eot');src: url('../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/font-bmi/font-bmi.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal}
`

Comment: Hmm ... You *shouldn't* need the first `src` property, can you try removing it, see if it still works?